# Why surt1000xli APC UPS recognised by NUT apcsmart driver as "old"?

Tags: linux, ups

So I have this UPS connected to machine with a RS232/USB cable.

`ups.conf` contains

```
[apc1]
    driver = apcsmart
    port = /dev/ttyUSB0
    desc = "APC USB"
```

And I get the following output:

```
$ sudo upsdrvctl start
Network UPS Tools - UPS driver controller 2.7.1
Network UPS Tools - APC Smart protocol driver 3.1 (2.7.1)
APC command table version 3.1
very old or unknown APC model, support will be limited
```